# Does a bigger WiFi channel bandwidth reduce range?

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth

Out of habit, I'm always choosing the smallest channel bandwidth in my WiFi setups to optimize range rather than throughput. Now I keep reading that the channel width does not affect range.

A long time ago, I've learned that effective transmit power depends on the bandwidth of your signal, as you're spreading your transmit power over a greater frequency range. For example SSB, single side band - essentially half an AM signal, is used in amateur radio to achieve greater ranges than with wider voice modes (AM/FM). The craziest of contacts are still made using "continuous wave" with Morse code, for that same reason.

If my assumption is correct, throughput over distance would be a mixed calculation, but the lowest bandwidth should provide the greatest possible range.

Is that a correct assumption, or are routers compensating for the higher power requirements? Or maybe there's something I'm missing?

Answer (score 4):

Aside from power considerations, the bandwidth has an obvious role in the calculation of the range because it affects the thermal noise of the receiver according to the sensitivity formula.

This has been very well explained by Ejohnson from the Aruba Networks forum: https://community.arubanetworks.com/t5/Wireless-Access/Channel-width-impacts-on-range/td-p/247117

Answer (score 2):

Those channel width settings only set the *maximum* channel width, not the *minimum*. Your Wi-Fi devices should automatically fall back to simpler modulation schemes (and narrower channels, if it would make a difference) as needed to optimize rate-at-range.

Also, I seem to recall that the regulatory power limits are measured across 1MHz or narrower slices, not the sum of the whole channel. So if the rule is that you can only use 1W in the 2.4GHz ISM band, it's that the power of any 1MHz-wide slice of your 20-, 40-, 80-, or 160MHz-wide channel may not exceed 1W. But don't quote me on that.

Channel frequency can have a much bigger effect in range than width, as radios using band-edge channels often use lower power to meet regulatory limits on out-of-band power bleedover. Also, in many regulatory environments, different sub-bands of the 5GHz band can have drastically different power limits. The regulations have changed over time, so it's hard to know for sure which rules your devices follow without testing them with proper RF lab equipment.

Answer (score -3):

Technically Bandwidth is the amount of data you can receive and transmit at a time. Range mainly depends on the length of antenna. So, if you use a bigger antenna, you can increase the range even on a greater bandwidth.

> thus bandwidth and range are independent.